# How do I loop through a cell range and name the cells with cell value in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and it works well, however, I'd like to loop through a cell range and name the cells in the range with the cell value:

```
Sub NameCell()
Range("A2").Name = Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: see this link: [Loop through each cell in a range of cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub NameMaker()
    For Each r In Selection
        With r
            .Name = .Value
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```