# Else If for whether a FileExists()

Tags: loops, excel, if-statement, vba

I need check whether a file that is produced daily, except on weekends and public/bank holidays, exists. The file name each day is based on the date, so I need the macro to do the following if I were to run it on a Sunday.

I need it to check whether the file exists (it won't on a Sunday), then subtract 1 day from the date in the file name and then test whether it exists again and continue this loop until it finds a file that does exist.

I have got most of the code so far, just struggling with the loop part:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Yday As Date
Dim YdayYear As Integer
Dim YdayMonth As Integer
Dim YdayDay As Integer
Dim CopyPath As String
Dim PastePath As String

i = 1
Yday = DateAdd("d", -i, Date)
YdayYear = DatePart("yyyy", Yday)
YdayMonth = DatePart("m", Yday)
YdayDay = DatePart("d", Yday)
CopyPath = "ABC\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"
PastePath = "XYZ\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"

If FileExists(CopyPath) Then
FileCopy Source:=CopyPath, Destination:=PastePath
    Else: i = i + 1
```

This is where I become stuck. How do I make it rerun the *If FileExists(CopyPath)* part of code?

Comment: Till when you want to keep searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a do while loop:

```
Do While Not FileExists(CopyPath)
    i = i +1
    Yday = DateAdd("d", -i, Date)
    YdayYear = DatePart("yyyy", Yday)
    YdayMonth = DatePart("m", Yday)
    YdayDay = DatePart("d", Yday)
    CopyPath = "ABC\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"
    PastePath = "XYZ\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"
Loop

FileCopy Source:=CopyPath, Destination:=PastePath
```

Comment: Why choose to define the list of variables within the loop, would it not work if I just had i = i +1 in the loop?

Comment: Sure you only need the `i = i + 1`, `Yday = DateAdd("d", -i, Date)` and the copypath part inside the loop. But then you'd need to do the copypath with the dateparts of Yday inside the copypath.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the Dir() function to check if a file exists:

```
If Dir(CopyPath) <> "" Then
    FileCopy Source:=CopyPath, Destination:=PastePath
Else
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something similar to the while loop suggested by Alex, but different and expanding a little on your actual requirements, and it could be argued that it is not a loop in a traditional for/while sense. For one, to avoid a while loop going on forever some counter and limit should be applied, in case no file exist. To also make it reusable if you want to automate a  traverse through a range of various Copy and Paste paths i took out the 'loop' part and placed it in a seperate function:

```
    Sub main()
        Dim vSuccess As Boolean
        Dim iterLimit As Integer ' iteration Limit, as in max number of times we want to go through
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim vDate As Date
        Dim copyFolder As String
        Dim pasteFolder As String

        iterLimit = 30 'for easier future followup, could be given directly into the function call
        i = 1 'same as above
        vDate = Date 'same as above
        copyFolder = "ABC\" 
        pasteFolder = "XYZ\" 

        vSuccess = IfDoesExist(copyFolder, pasteFolder, vDate, i, iterLimit) 'put it into the function IfDoesExist

        If vSuccess Then 'if the funciton returns True a match was found and the file copied
            MsgBox "Success, the file was copied"
        Else 'if not then do something
            MsgBox "No file found"
        End If

    End Sub



    Function IfDoesExist(copyFolder As String, pasteFolder As String, vDate As Date, i As Integer, iterLimit As Integer)
        Dim Yday As Date
        Dim YdayYear As Integer
        Dim YdayMonth As Integer
        Dim YdayDay As Integer
        Dim CopyPath As String
        Dim PastePath As String


        Yday = DateAdd("d", -i, vDate)
        YdayYear = DatePart("yyyy", Yday)
        YdayMonth = DatePart("m", Yday)
        YdayDay = DatePart("d", Yday)
        CopyPath = copyFolder & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"
        PastePath = pasteFolder & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"

        If iterLimit > 0 Then
            If Dir(CopyPath) <> "" Then
                FileCopy Source:=CopyPath, Destination:=PastePath
                vStatus = True 'we have a match
            Else 'if the file doesn't exist we want to rerun all of the above with a new i and iterLimit
                iterLimit = iterLimit - 1
                i = i + 1
                'Ok i know the next line of code may seem odd, but you will get True or False.
                'When the function stops calling itself the vStatus is either true because a 
                'match was eventually found, or false if it ws not. The value then travels back
                'through the calls/stack and ends up in the main programme.
                '
                'put in a breakpoint an take a look at the locals if you want to see the magic happen
                vStatus = IfDoesExist(copyFolder, pasteFolder, Date, i, iterLimit)
            End If
        Else
            vStatus = False 'if a match was never found within iterLimit calls
        End If

        IfDoesExist = vStatus 'return vStatus
    End Function
```

This is perhaps to overcomplicate things, but I had fun doing it. Though there is no while or for loop the function will effectivly work the same by calling itself. To avoid an infinite number of iterations, the iterLimit is decremented by 1 for each call.

The template to go over a range of paths, is not applied in the code but if you look at [Loop through each cell in a range of cells when given a Range object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object) you may get an idea of how it could be done

modified for paths it worked on my system, but if you are up for trying and it fails on your system, please let me know which error you get

EDIT:

to answer your question in short, a for loop should do it:

```
        Sub main2()
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim Yday As Date
            Dim YdayYear As Integer
            Dim YdayMonth As Integer
            Dim YdayDay As Integer
            Dim CopyPath As String
            Dim PastePath As String
            Dim vMax As Integer
            Dim vStatus As Boolean

            vMax = 30

            For i = 1 To vMax
                Yday = DateAdd("d", -i, Date)
                YdayYear = DatePart("yyyy", Yday)
                YdayMonth = DatePart("m", Yday)
                YdayDay = DatePart("d", Yday)
                CopyPath = "ABC\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"
                PastePath = "XYZ\" & YdayYear & YdayMonth & YdayDay & ".csv"

                If FileExists(CopyPath) Then
                    FileCopy Source:=CopyPath, Destination:=PastePath
                    vStatus = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next

            If Not vStatus = True Then
                MsgBox "File Not found"
            End If
        End Sub
```