# Is there a way to tell when one cell is below another?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using excel vba, and I'm trying to do a loop until the ranges I'm dealing with go beyond some other pre-defined range.

For example, I'd set one range to `range("A10000")`, and I'd like to loop on the a column until something passed that point.

Psudo-code of what I'd like is below.

```
dim myRange as range
dim maxRange as range

do while myRange < maxRange
  ' do something
  ' range.address = range.address next one '(range("a450") becomes range("a451"))
end while
```

EDIT:  The reason I'm looking explicitly for a comparison to terminate the loop is because I can't assume a well-defined space that I can do a straight-forward loop over each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Public Sub TEST()


    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim maxRange As Range
    Dim i as Integer
    Set myRange = Sheets(1).Range("A2")
    Set maxRange = Sheets(1).Range("A5")

    Do While myRange.Row < maxRange.Row
      ' do something
      ' range.address = range.address next one '(range("a450") becomes range("a451"))
      i = myRange.Row + 1
      Set myRange = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i)
    Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Though Edward's answer seems like a perfectly reasonable way to tackle this challenge (`Range.row` ought to get you where you're going), when I need to operate on `Range` objects and have a really well-defined space I reach for the [`For Each Cell in Range`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object) construct.

Here's a tiny example:

```
Dim rngTarget As Range, rngCell As Range

Set rngTarget = Sheets(1).Range("A2:A10000")

For Each rngCell In rngTarget
    'do cool stuff to rngCell
Next rngCell
```

And there you have it! I particularly like this method because it is concise, handles movement in the x and y-direction without juggling columns/rows and reads easily.

Comment: I'd go with this one if I were to do the same.

Comment: Agreed this a good method, but if for some reason he is looking to compare range values, than my method might be the way to go. Just answering the question as presented.

Comment: @EdwardBagby, The reason I was looking to compare range values is because I don't expect to always increment by a value of one.  The problem is that I don't have a well-defined space to work with, so there's going to be a lot of "hopping around", and I needed a termination clause.  Thanks so much for your help, btw.  (I can edit the original question to make the context more clear.)

Comment: Yes, you are welcome.  Actually I had thought to comment to that I usually prefer explicit loops over ones based on less code, if practical.  The intention is obvious and there's more control for unusual circumstances.  For example, a two-dimensional array of cells using Dan's code may not cycle through those dimensions the way you prefer.