# VBA Macro - I want to change each cell value to a new one in a specific range... how to do it? Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range that is B3:B500
I want to change the value in each cell in that range
The range however, is dynamic so I need to look from B3 to last row

First:
How do I get it to change the range to work to last row rather than preset range?

Second:
I want to change each individual cell value to something like this:

myCell.Value = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(61) & myCell.Value & Chr(34)

How do I get it to go through cell by cell to make change to each cell in the "dynamic" range we just created?

Appreciate all the help I can get... pretty new at VBA so please bear that in mind and keep it simple :)

I.e. Cell b3 contains: "ASP" (Text only)
Change to: ="="ASP" (formula instead giving result =ASP)

Comment: what code have you *tried*? Or even looked for? [Looping over a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object), [Methods for getting the last row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: Hi, Yes thank you I have looked at them, but I am very new to VBA don't really understand what all that means. I would appreciate a bit of explaination as to what each section is doing... sorry for the inconvinience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = 3
Dim myCell As Range
'determine last row of current region
Do While(Not IsEmpty(Cells(lastRow + 1, 2)))
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
Loop
'loop through the range
For Each myCell In Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))
    myCell.Value = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(61) & myCell.Value & Chr(34)
Next myCell
```

In this code, first you determine last row using `While` loop, which loops until the last row in column is found. Then use `For Each` loop, where you loop through the range, from third row to last row in B column.

Comment: `CurrentRegion` seems like an odd choice here?

Comment: Thank you for this, seems however that it adds the works on column C rather than B? Do I need to set range to b3?

Comment: Sory for that, my mistake. Should work as desired now.

Comment: Works amazingly... thanks a million!   so, to understand...
For Each myCell In Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))   ---> lastRow,"2" and Cells(2, "2"    --> the 2s in "" refer to the column number from the sheet start... i.e. 2 here is column 2 = column B ?

Sorry about this, just trying to learn more about VBA

Comment: Generally: `Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex)`, both parameters are integers, specyfying row and column. For rows it's easy, for columns: 1 = A, 2 = B, etc., just like you expected.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `columnIndex` can be a string for the column, so you can use `ActiveSheet.Cells(4, "B")` for Cell "B4"

Comment: Fantastic, thank you all for the great help... works great and understand a bit better VBA, think I need to continue learning :)