# Get All the Attributes and value in XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am using VBA to get All the attributes and values from the XML parent node.

Here is the XML:

```
<Elements>
   <Details>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <Address>123ABC</Address>
   </Details>   
   <Dept>
      <Deptname>IT</Deptname>
      <ID>A123</ID>
   </Dept>  
</Elements>
```

This is the code I am using in VBA

```vb
sub test() 
    Dim XMLFile As Object
    Dim XMLFileName As String
    Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    XMLFileName = "C:\Users\Input.xml"
    XMLFile.async = False
    XMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
    XMLFile.validateOnParse = False

    Dim mainnode As Object
    Dim node As Object

    Set mainnode = XMLFile.SelectNodes("//Elements")

    For Each node In mainnode
        Dim child As Variant
        For Each child In node.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print child.Name
        Next child
    Next node
End sub
```

This is the output I am expecting.

```
Details
Name
Address
Dept
deptname
ID
```

I am getting errors executing the above code. Could someone help me in getting this resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Thumbs up for the late binding in the question!

Comment: AFAIK it's preferrable to use the **`MSXML2`** namespace as the old `Microsoft.XMLDOM` one is only maintained for *legacy Support*. Thus late binding the recommended version 6 can be obtained via `Set XMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` after the object declaration `Dim XMLFile As Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) sample `Name` and `Address` are childern of `Details`. The below code retruns `Details` and `Dept`:

```
For Each node In mainnode
    Dim child As Object
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print child.BaseName
    Next child
Next node
```

---

If you want the children of `Details` and `Dept`, you need to go one level deeper:

```
For Each node In mainnode
    Dim child As Object
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print child.BaseName
        Dim kiddo As Object
        For Each kiddo In child.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print kiddo.BaseName
        Next kiddo
    Next child
Next node
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This works.
I am also trying to write the attributes to an excel , but I am getting the "Dept" written twice on my excel.

`For Each node In mainnode
    Dim child As Object
    For i = 0 To node.ChildNodes.Length - 1
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes
                'Debug.Print child.BaseName
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value = child.BaseName
                 Next child
                Next
                Next node`

Comment: @vityala - How do I write the records to an excel. I am using a 'for' loop to perform this operation, it is not giving the result as I expected

Comment: @Raja - for loop is the way to go. Or for - each. Anyway, this sounds like a new question, just put some code and a sample and you would get an answer. Or see this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object

Comment: For the stylish answer +1

Comment: @Vityata - Is there a way I could handle repeating tags in the xml ?. Asking this question since I do get same <details> tag for multiple members.   I do not want the same tagname to be written twice in my result. Thanks!

Comment: @Raja - take a look at the dictionary structure in VBA and add the tags to a dictionary. Then loop through the keys, it should be quite ok.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to add the dictionary. I am missing something in my code. 

       ' Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
          For Each node In mainnode
            Dim child As Object
        
                 i = 0
                 For Each child In node.ChildNodes
           
                
                If Not Exists(child.BaseName) Then
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value = child.BaseName'

Comment: @Raja - I am a bit afk now, but it is probably a good idea to ask a separate question. Or to check the top "dictionary" questions in vba and excel in SO, something useful will pop up.

Comment: @Vityata - Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Vityata - How do I get the "num" attribute of the XML.

`<Dept num=123>
  <name>A</name>
</Dept>`

Comment: @Raja - I have to check, but you can really profit if you ask it as a separate question. Just make sure to add a bit of code and the XML, probably in less than 30 minutes you would have an answer :)

Comment: @Vityata - it might be of interest to see my answer to assign an entire XML structure to an 2-dim array determine the number of elements via `XPath/XMLDOM` and optionally write the whole info back to a sheet via **recursive calls** - see [Obtain Attribute names from XML using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the expected result with the below code

```
For Each node In mainnode
Dim child As Object
'For i = 0 To node.ChildNodes.Length - 1
i = 0
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes


            Debug.Print child.BaseName
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value = child.BaseName

            'i = i + 1

            Dim kiddo As Object
                For Each kiddo In child.ChildNodes
                Debug.Print kiddo.BaseName
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i + 1).Value = kiddo.BaseName
                i = i + 1
                Next kiddo
            Next child
            Next node
```

When my XML contains only attributes without the tags, the above code is not picking the node.

Updated XML:
     `<Elements>
    <Details>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Address>123ABC</Address>
    </Details>

    <Dept num = "123" >
        <Deptname>IT</Deptname>
        <ID>A123</ID>
        <ID1>A123</ID1>
    </Dept> 
</Elements>`

The Child node: "num" is not getting displayed . Is there anything I am missing in my code. ?