# Obtain attribute names from XML using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmldom

I need to get the distinct attributes names from the XML using VBA.

this is my code.

```
 sub test() 
 Dim XMLFile As Object
Dim XMLFileName As String
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

XMLFileName = "C:\Users\Input.xml"
XMLFile.async = False
XMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
XMLFile.validateOnParse = False

Dim mainnode As Object
Dim node As Object

Set mainnode = XMLFile.SelectNodes("//Elements")

For Each node In mainnode
    For Each child In node.ChildNodes
    Debug.Print child.BaseName
    Dim kiddo As Object
    For Each kiddo In child.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print kiddo.BaseName
    Next kiddo
Next child
Next node
End sub
```

Here is the sample XML. I need to get the attribute name `num` from the XML.

```
<Elements>
<Details>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Address>123ABC</Address>
    <College>
        <collname>safasf</collname>
         <collnumber/>
    </College>
</Details>  
<Dept num="123">
    <Deptname>IT</Deptname>
    <ID>A123</ID>
 </Dept>            
</Elements>
```

Expected Result:

```
 Elements
 Details
 Name 
 Address
 College
 collname
 collnumber
 Dept
 num
 Deptname
 ID
```

Actual Result from above code:

```
 Elements
 Details
 Name 
 Address
 College
 collname
 Dept
 Deptname
 ID
```

The "num" attribute and `<collnumber/>` tag is not fetched by my code. Could someone let me know how to fetch the attribute names along with the tag names  from XML using VBA

Comment: So you've told us what you want to do.  What about the code you've shared is not working?  [Edit] your post and Include expected result, actual result and any error messages. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Possibly [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Added a working example how to assign an entire XML structure to a 2-dim array via recursive calls using `XMLDOM` and write it to a sheet optionally. See additional hints suggesting to discover XSLT approaches, too *(c.f. many posts delivered e.g. by @Parfait ).*

Comment: @Raja - edited and improved my answer showing a way to determine the exact element items count or to define an estimated number automatically corrected by the called function listChildNodes(). Furthermore it's possible to choose a precise node to get its structure instead of the entire file set. - Did you try my solution so that you can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 9):

**Displaying  XML structures including attributes via recursive function calls**

My example code  demonstrates a way to

- `[1]` assign the entire XML structure to a 2-dim array using XMLDOM methods and
- `[2]` optionally write it back to a sheet.

**Amplifying hints:**

I added these ► structured hints to offer more **help** than by displaying code only, as I remarked that many of these points lead to repeated questions by other users, too:

- Trying to list  `XML` structures you lose good view  with increasing  hierarchy  depth of your node elements (type constant  1 `NODE_ELEMENT`), so I urgently recommend the use of ► **recursive  calls**  as used in this example code.
- Furthermore you might have not considered the special construction of **node text** (type constant 3 `NODE_TEXT`) being  the **first child** of  a name giving *parent element*  -  c.f. sections A. and B. in main function `listChildNodes`.  *Your loops through child nodes would not  distinguish between the mentioned types.* Just study the comments in the cited function for details.
- I suppose your XML file starts with a needed **processing instruction** like e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, so that it can be actually identified as XML file.
- The calling procedure `DisplayXML()` uses **late binding** instead of early bound reference to MS XML similar to your post, but uses the recommended  **MSXML2 version 6.0**.  It calls the main function via its `DocumentElement` `<Elements>`  (*BTW a single node element*) and a second argument referring to a predefined 2-dim array `v`.
- **Versioning:** If you would set your `XMLFILE` object  to memory with `Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")`  generally you are getting the older  default Version (3.0), so in most cases it's preferrable to use explicitly `Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`  instead (including XPath automatically).
- If you don't use the **`Load`** function to get a `True` (file loaded successfully) or `False` (load error) back, it is not necessary to set the file name into brackets ().
- The XPath operator `//` in search strings would return any occurences at *any* level (c.f. `XMLFile.SelectNodes("//Elements")` in your OP).
- Consider  also the use of **XSLT**, a special-purpose language designed to tranform XML files into all kind of end-use formats.

**Calling procedure `DisplayXML`**

*Hint:* It would sufficient to dimension the array 's row count only with an estimated number of items in the calling procedure (e.g. 1000), as the main function executes a `ReDim` (including a double transposition) automatically if needed. Nevertheless I added the exact items count here from the start via XPath/XMLDOM expression `XMLFile.SelectNodes("//*").Length` counting any item in the entire file.

```
Option Explicit          ' declaration head of your code module

Sub DisplayXML()
Dim XMLFile As Object
Dim XMLFileName As String
'Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")   ' former style not recommended
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

XMLFileName = "C:\Users\Input.xml"                             ' << change to your xml file name
XMLFile.Async = False
XMLFile.ValidateOnParse = False
Debug.Print XMLFile.XML

If XMLFile.Load(XMLFileName) Then
' [1] write xml info to array with exact or assumed items count
  Dim v As Variant: ReDim v(1 To XMLFile.SelectNodes("//*").Length, 1 To 2)
  listChildNodes XMLFile.DocumentElement, v                 ' call helper function

' [2] write results to sheet "Dump"                         ' change to your sheet name
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dump")
       .Range("A:B") = ""                                   ' clear result range
       .Range("A1:B1") = Split("XML Tag,Node Value", ",")   ' titles
       .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v     ' get  2-dim info array
  End With
Else
       MsgBox "Load Error " & XMLFileName
End If
Set XMLFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Structured results displayed in sheet**

*Hint*: If you don't want the level indentation or enumerated Level hierarchy, you can easily adapt the main function `listChildNodes()` below.

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|    |         A           |       B         |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|1   | XML Tag             | Node Value      |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|2   | 0 Elements          |                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|3   |   1 Details         |                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|4   |     2 Name          | ABC             |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|5   |     2 Address       | 123ABC          |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|6   |     2 College       |                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|7   |       3 collname    | safasf          |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|8   |       3 collnumber  |                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|9   |   1 Dept[@num="123"]|                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|10  |     2 Deptname      | IT              |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|11  |     2 ID            | A123            |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
```

It is also possible to refer to a precise node element, e.g. via

```
listChildNodes XMLFile.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Dept[@num=""123""]"),v, 1, 1       ' starting from item no 1 and Level no 1
```

This would list the indicated node set alone:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|    |         A           |       B         |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|1   | XML Tag             | Node Value      |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|2   |   1 Dept[@num="123"]|                 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|3   |     2 Deptname      | IT              |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|4   |     2 ID            | A123            |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
```

**Recursive main function `listChildNodes()`**

Looping through childnode collections this function calls itself (i.e. the current node object) repeatedly ("recursively") and assigns the entire XML structure to a given 2-dim array (2nd argument). Furthermore it allows indendation and indicates the hierarchy levels. *Note that the array in this example has to be 1-based.*

`Edit 20/8 2018` includes an **automatic increase of array size** if the items counter `i` exceeds the current array's upper boundary (`UBound(v)`, i.e. in its first dimension = items count). *Technical note: As such a `ReDim` isn't possible in a minor (here 1st) dimension, an intermediate transposition changing 'rows' (dim 1) to 'columns' (dim 2) is necessary.*

```
Function listChildNodes(oCurrNode As Object, _
                        ByRef v As Variant, _
                        Optional ByRef i As Long = 1, _
                        Optional iLvl As Integer = 0 _
                        ) As Boolean
' Purpose: assign the complete node structure with contents to a 1-based 2-dim array
' Author:  T.M.
' Note: Late binding XML doesn't allow the use of IXMLDOMNodeType enumeration constants
'       (1 ... NODE_ELEMENT, 2 ... NODE_ATTRIBUTE, 3 ... NODE_TEXT etc.)
' Escape
  If oCurrNode Is Nothing Then Exit Function
  If i < 1 Then i = 1                                       ' one based items Counter
' Edit 20/8 2018 - Automatic increase of array size if needed 
  If i >= UBound(v) Then                                    ' change array size if needed
     Dim tmp As Variant
     tmp = Application.Transpose(v)                         ' change rows to columns
     ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(v) + 1000)      ' increase row numbers
     v = Application.Transpose(tmp)                         ' transpose back
     Erase tmp
  End If
  Const NAMEColumn& = 1, VALUEColumn& = 2                   ' constants for column 1 and 2
' Declare variables
  Dim oChildNode As Object                                  ' late bound node object
  Dim bDisplay   As Boolean
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
' A. It's nothing but a TextNode (i.e. a parent node's firstChild!)
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
If (oCurrNode.NodeType = 3) Then                                 ' 3 ... NODE_TEXT
  ' display pure text content (NODE_TEXT) of parent elements
    v(i, VALUEColumn) = oCurrNode.Text                           ' nodeValue of text node
  ' return
    listChildNodes = True
ElseIf oCurrNode.NodeType = 1 Then                                ' 1 ... NODE_ELEMENT
   ' --------------------------------------------------------------
   ' B.1 NODE_ELEMENT WITHOUT text node immediately below,
   '     a) e.g. <Details> followed by node element <NAME>,
   '        (i.e. FirstChild.NodeType must not be of type NODE_TEXT = 3)
   '     b) e.g. <College> node element without any child node
   '     Note: a text content (NODE_TEXT) actually is a child node(!) to an element node
   '           (see section A. getting the FirstChild of a NODE_ELEMENT)
   ' --------------------------------------------------------------
   ' a) display parent elements of other element nodes
     If oCurrNode.HasChildNodes Then
         If Not oCurrNode.FirstChild.NodeType = 3 Then             ' <>3 ... not a NODE_TEXT
            bDisplay = True
         End If
   ' b) always display empty node elements
     Else                                                           ' empty NODE_ELEMENT
            bDisplay = True
     End If
     If bDisplay Then
            v(i, NAMEColumn) = String(iLvl * 2, " ") & _
                               iLvl & " " & _
                               oCurrNode.nodename & getAtts(oCurrNode)
            i = i + 1
     End If

   ' --------------------------------------------------------------
   ' B.2 check child nodes
   ' --------------------------------------------------------------
     For Each oChildNode In oCurrNode.ChildNodes
      ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ' recursive call <<
      ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        bDisplay = listChildNodes(oChildNode, v, i, iLvl + 1)

        If bDisplay Then
            v(i, NAMEColumn) = String(iLvl * 2, " ") & _
                               iLvl & " " & _
                               oCurrNode.nodename & getAtts(oCurrNode)
            i = i + 1
        End If
     Next oChildNode
   ' return
     listChildNodes = False

Else    ' just to demonstrate the use of other xml types as e.g. <!-- comments -->
     If oCurrNode.NodeType = 8 Then   ' 8 ... NODE_COMMENT
        v(i, VALUEColumn) = "<!-- " & oCurrNode.NodeValue & "-->"
        i = i + 1
     End If
   ' return
     listChildNodes = False
End If

End Function
```

'**Helper function `getAtts()`**

This helper function called by the above function returns a string enumerating all *attribute* names and values of a given node similar to `XPath` notation; the code can be easily adapted to your needs.

```
Function getAtts(ByRef node As Object) As String
' Purpose: return attribute(s) string in brackets, e.g. '[@num="123"]'
' Note:    called by above function listChildNodes()
' Author:  T.M.
  Dim sAtts$, ii&
  If node.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
      ii = 0: sAtts = ""
      For ii = 0 To node.Attributes.Length - 1
        sAtts = sAtts & "[@" & node.Attributes.Item(ii).nodename & "=""" & node.Attributes.Item(ii).NodeValue & """]"
      Next ii
  End If
' return
  getAtts = sAtts
End Function
```