# VBA Excel: Loop through XML Attributes

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm actually building a programme in excel to fill in data into a word document from a webservice.
Because the XML is built up in a strange way, I have to loop through the attributes of a node, to create a list. From this list I will create a table.

My problem is this loop, I'll show you the code:

```
    ConnectionString = "//GetConfigurationItems/ConfigurationItem/AttachmentTypes/AttachmentType"
tblFilter = "1D8651D1-99E2-4D77-9BFF-1A667AA9398D"
id = "14"

            Set valuesOXML = CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
            valuesOXML.LoadXML DMIService.execute(Webservice, functionName, portName, "<![CDATA[<GetConfigurationItems><ConfigurationItem ID=""" & ID & """ Filter=""" & tblFilter & """ Deleted=""0""/></GetConfigurationItems>]]>")

            Set fourthNameField = valuesOXML.SelectNodes(ConnectionString)
            For Each ftfield In fourthNameField
                werte = werte & ftfield.Attributes(0).Text & ";"

                Dim x As Integer
                For x = 0 To ftfield.Attributes.Item - 1
                     Debug.Print ftfield.Attributes.Item(x)
                Next x
            Next ftfield
```

The command to save the werte variable is working. but the Loop through the attributes fails with the failure-Text:

> "Object doens't support this property or method".

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetConfigurationItems Error="False">
    <ConfigurationItem ID="14" Filter="1D8651D1-99E2-4D77-9BFF-1A667AA9398D" Deleted="0">
        <AttachmentTypes DropDownType="14" Filter="1D8651D1-99E2-4D77-9BFF-1A667AA9398D" Deleted="0">
            <AttachmentType ShortDesc="BOA_FIT" VersionNo="2" ID="1D8651D1-99E2-4D77-9BFF-1A667AA9398D">FIT</AttachmentType>
        </AttachmentTypes>
    </ConfigurationItem>
</GetConfigurationItems>
```

Comment: what is `ConnectionString`? I can't see it in the XML provided. Also, what value is given to `tblFilter`? used in the *LoadXML*

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this one.. its initialized further up..
ConnectionString = //GetConfigurationItems/ConfigurationItem/AttachmentTypes/AttachmentType

Comment: AFAIK MSXML2 Version 4.0 is obsolete, try Version 6.0 instead ; cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221640/vba-excel-loop-trough-xml-attributes#52221640

Comment: `For x = 0 To ftfield.Attributes.Length - 1`

Comment: PS - correct link is [Obtain attribute names from XML using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)

Comment: thanks for the link. also very helpfull. and also thanks axel richter, your answer is also the right solution for what i was looking for.. sometimes the solution is so easy :) but i was just stuck somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (works in VBA using the XML as as string)

> I added MSXML2 library as a Reference (Tools > References > Microsoft XML, v6.0)**

```
Dim valuesOXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60 

Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim fourthNameField As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim ftfield As IXMLDOMNode
Dim werte As String

ConnectionString = "//GetConfigurationItems/ConfigurationItem/AttachmentTypes/AttachmentType"

Set valuesOXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

valuesOXML.LoadXML  DMIService.execute(Webservice, functionName, portName, "<![CDATA[<GetConfigurationItems><ConfigurationItem ID=""" & ID & """ Filter=""" & tblFilter & """ Deleted=""0""/></GetConfigurationItems>]]>")

Set fourthNameField = valuesOXML.SelectNodes(ConnectionString)
For Each ftfield In fourthNameField
    werte = werte & ftfield.Attributes(0).Text & ";"

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To ftfield.Attributes.Length - 1
         Debug.Print ftfield.Attributes.Item(x).Text
    Next x
Next ftfield
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly the case.. with For x = 0 To ftfield.Attributes.Length - 1 it is working. thanks a lot. i just started with stackoverflow and this was my first question. im overwhelmed by all the people try to help me so fast! thanks a lot!!

Comment: @LucaS: Your're welcome, so long as you ask a good question like that, with example code, clearly explaining the problem, you're likely to get good useful, helpful responses and upvotes, which gives you reputaion

Answer (score 1):

Are you not doing the equivalent of the following? Replace my loading from file with your connection code.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, mainNode As Object, Node As Object, child As Object, child2 As Object
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Set mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//GetConfigurationItems")

    For Each Node In mainNode
        For Each child In Node.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print child.BaseName & " :" & child.Text
            For Each child2 In child.ChildNodes
               Debug.Print child2.BaseName & " : " & child2.Text
            Next
        Next
    Next Node
End Sub
```

---

With attributes:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, mainNode As Object, Node As Object, child As Object, child2 As Object, i As Long
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Set mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//GetConfigurationItems")

    For Each Node In mainNode
        For Each child In Node.ChildNodes
            If child.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To child.Attributes.Length - 1
                    Debug.Print child.BaseName & " : " & child.Attributes(i).nodeName & " - " & child.Attributes(i).NodeValue; ""
                Next
            End If
            For Each child2 In child.ChildNodes
                If child2.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To child2.Attributes.Length - 1
                    Debug.Print child2.BaseName & " : " & child2.Attributes(i).nodeName & " - " & child2.Attributes(i).NodeValue
                Next
            End If
            Next
        Next
    Next Node
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its not what a try to achieve.. i have to get a list with all the attributes from a node.. but thanks for your help anyway!! the other guys gave me the solution :)

Comment: oops... my bad... so you wanted a list of the attrbibutes and their values? Or just the attributes?

Comment: first just the attribute names.. because im gonna create a table out of the list of attributes.. later i will also need to get the values. but thats not the problem of today :)