# LoadXML in VBA not parsing string into usable DOMDocument60

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xml-parsing

long time reader, but first post on here. Any and all help is highly appreciated!

I am working on a data scraper to obtain our clients' market results from the grid operator, and require a series of xml queries to do so. I am able to connect, authenticate and receive a response to my query using SOAP schema (required by grid operator). However, when I try to load the xml string I receive from the server into a DOMDocument60 object using the LoadXML function, it strips all of the nodes from the response and results in an xml document with only the header in one node and a concatenation of all the values stored in all nodes of the string in a second node.

Hence, I cannot extract the values I need. They have varying lengths and I have no way of knowing when one value finishes and the next one starts. Additionally, because the node names have been stripped, when I try and obtain a node list of all nodes called "DSRSRREGAwardHourly" I get an empty list.

**XML received from server after querying (I've left only one of the hourly nodes to simplify)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <QueryResponse xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml">
      <DSRSRREGAwardSet>
        <DSRSRREGAward day="2018-12-01" location="1960147390">
          <DSRSRREGAwardHourly hour="1">
            <SynchOfferMW>0.5</SynchOfferMW>
            <RegOfferMW>0</RegOfferMW>
            <SelfScheduledMW>0</SelfScheduledMW>
            <SynchAwardedMW>0</SynchAwardedMW>
            <RegAwardedMW>0</RegAwardedMW>
            <RegOfferPriceUsed>0</RegOfferPriceUsed>
            <RegdOfferMW>0</RegdOfferMW>
            <RegdMW>0</RegdMW>
          </DSRSRREGAwardHourly>
        </DSRSRREGAward>
      </DSRSRREGAwardSet>
    </QueryResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Relevant VBA code I'm using**

```vb
'Variable definition
Dim oWinhttp As WinHttpRequest
Dim ReturnXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim ItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim XMLItem As IXMLDOMNode

'Variable initialization
Set oWinhttp = New WinHttpRequest
Set ReturnXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Run the query against the server
With oWinhttp
  Call .Open("POST", WebURL)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "pjmauth=" & tokenStr)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Length", Len(xmlSubmittal))
  Call .Send(xmlSubmittal)
  Call .WaitForResponse

  'Store the return XML into DOM Document
  ReturnXML.async = False
  ReturnXML.validateOnParse = False
  ReturnXML.LoadXML (.ResponseText)

  'Terminate connection
  Call oWinhttp.abort
End With

'Extract nodes we are going to need
Set ItemList = ReturnXML.SelectNodes("//DSRSRREGAwardHourly")
```

Comment: I posted before going to bed, and today has been crazy, but it worked like a charm, thanks @T.M.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple XML parsing using name spaces**

Try the following code lines

- [1] setting a name space definition via

  ReturnXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNameSpaces

where `xmlNameSpaces` is just a string variable replicating a prior Namespace (`xmlns`) attribute within the `<QueryResponse>` node.

- [2] Executing *very basic loops* through the node structure. As apparently there are only subnodes with textual entries in each node, this code example doesn't check for empty nodes (*Consider using more elaborated XPath parsing and/or the use of the special - platform independant - query language `XSLT`*).

**Relevant code snippet**

```
' ...
'[1] Store the return XML into DOM Document using name spaces defining a leading "d:" prefix
ReturnXML.async = False
ReturnXML.validateOnParse = False

Dim xmlNameSpaces$
xmlNameSpaces = "xmlns:d=""http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml"""      ' define namespaces
ReturnXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNameSpaces      ' set namespace prop

ReturnXML.LoadXML (.ResponseText)                   ' get content

'[2] Loop through node lists (attention to the chosen namespace prefix)
Dim ItemList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, ItemList2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim item As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, item2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Set ItemList = ReturnXML.SelectNodes("//d:DSRSRREGAwardHourly") ' <~~ leading "d:" :-)

For Each item In ItemList
     Debug.Print "Day:  " & item.SelectSingleNode("../@day").Text, _
                 "Hour: " & item.SelectSingleNode("./@hour").Text
     Set ItemList2 = item.SelectNodes("d:*")
     For Each item2 In ItemList2
        Debug.Print vbTab & item2.nodeName, item2.Text
     Next item2
Next item
```

**Related link**

C.f. [Obtain attribute names from XML using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)

**Addendum due to comment**

> "I'm curious now, was the problem that the string had 2 different namespaces defined and hence was ignoring the second one?"

Basically *yes*; the latter declaration in hierarchy reigns over the prior one in your xml data example *(with exception of explicitly prefixed element names)*.

- a) The whole XML structure in the concrete example only shows *"normal"* = unprefixed element names such as `<SynchOfferMW>` (instead of a possible `<extra:SynchOfferMW>` which would be based on an additional explicit prefix assignment within a prior namespace declaration `xmlns:extra="http://..."`). With unprefixed namespaces you are declaring two **default namespaces**, one for the `<Envelope>` element, the second for the `<QueryResponse>` element.
- b) Due to the [w3.org definition of namespaces/6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)  *"the scope of a ► default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. ... A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope."* So the `<QueryResponse>` element and all its (unprefixed) descendants of this example belong to the second **default namespace**.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks for your insight! I'm curious now, was the problem that the string had 2 different namespaces defined and hence was ignoring the second one?

Comment: Added additional explanations answering your question in comment - @Angel