# How to Print the All Child and Parent tag and value in Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, scripting

Below is the Xml file

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <note>
        <Example id= "exmaple111">
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <heading>Reminder</heading>
          <message>Don't forget me this weekend!</message>
        <body>
        <template> to be displayed..</template>
        </body>
        <Me> 
            <test> please print </test>
            <test2> 22 </test2> 
        </Me>
        <Extra> Extra </Extra>
        </Example>
         </note>
```

```
I have Written below Code
```

```vb
     xml.Load (TextBox1.Value)
        Dim XmlNode  As IXMLDOMNode
        Set XmlNode = xml.DocumentElement
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = XmlNode.xml
        
        Set Books = xml.SelectNodes("/note/*")
        
      For i = 0 To Books.Length - 1
            For j = 0 To Books(i).ChildNodes.Length - 1
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & intCounter).Value = j + 1
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & intCounter).Value = Books(i).ChildNodes(j).NodeName         ' Edit: instead of ".tagName"
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & intCounter).Value = Books(i).ChildNodes(j).Text
               intCounter = intCounter + 1
            Next
             intCounter = intCounter + 1
        Next
```

**But it is only printing the parent node and with in which it is printing the child not value .
But I need the name of the child note also like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqxNO.png)

Comment: You aren't aware of the node hierarchy; a node's  `.Text` property displays a joined string of a all subnodes. Therefore I suggest recursive calls checking for the next hierarchy level. - You find a quite close solution at [Display XML with hierarchy in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373293/vba-display-xml-with-hierarchy-in-cells/65380287#65380287). Feel free to upvote this if helpful as a starter :-) @user15527478

Comment: Posted a *detailed* solution to your question; feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark near the answer if helpful and your preferred answer. @user15527478

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessDoc()

    Dim xml As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim depth As Integer, n As Long
    Dim root As IXMLDOMNode
    
    xml.LoadXML Range("A1").Value ' or TextBox1.Value
    Set root = xml.SelectSingleNode("/")
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    depth = 0
    n = 0

    ProcessNode root, depth, rng, n
    MsgBox n & " lines written to " & rng.Address, vbInformation

End Sub

Sub ProcessNode(parent As IXMLDOMNode, depth As Integer, rng As Range, n As Long)
    Const MAX_DEPTH = 10 ' limit
    Dim child As IXMLDOMNode

    If parent Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf depth > MAX_DEPTH Then
        MsgBox "Exceeded depth limit of " & MAX_DEPTH, vbCritical, "Depth=" & depth
    ElseIf parent.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each child In parent.ChildNodes
            If child.NodeType = 3 Then 'NODE_TEXT
                rng.Offset(n, 0) = n + 1
                rng.Offset(n, 1) = parent.nodeName
                rng.Offset(n, 2) = child.Text
                n = n + 1
            ElseIf child.HasChildNodes Then
                ProcessNode child, depth + 1, rng, n ' recurse
            End If
         Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't output the `<Me>` and `<body>` node names as demanded in OP. - btw VBA doesn't know the `Return` command :-; @CDP1802

Comment: @T.M. Yes, didn't see the point showing the opening tags without the closing ones and I tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Parse XML node names and content**

> *"But it is only printing the parent node and
> with in which it is printing the child not value.
> But I need the name of the *child note* (sic!) also."*

The original post doesn't take into account the special xml node hierarchy:

- A node element can dispose or not of one or several childnodes.
- A node's childnode can be a text element or itself e.g. a node element.
- A node's `.Text` property *alone* displays a joined string of the text elements of *any* subordinated childnodes.

So each complete parse action over several hierarchy levels includes a check for child nodes (`.HasChildNodes` property).
In order not to loose a clear view over nested levels I urgently recommend a recursive approach.
This will be demonstrated by the main function `listChildNodes()`.

This function uses *late binding*, but could be changed to early binding, too
by modifying the object declarations to precise MSXML2 declaration types.
Note that early binding would also use a slightly different DOMDocument type identification:

```
    '(Early binding)
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60     ' (or MSXML2.DOMDocument for old version 3.0)
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60  ' set instance to memory
```

```
    'LATE Binding
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
```

To allow other users to avoid writing and saving an external file, it would be possible to load a xlm content string directly via **`.LoadXML`** (instead of `.Load`)

```
     Dim XMLContentString as String
     XMLContentString = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note>...</note>"
     If xDoc.LoadXML(XMLContentString) Then
     ' ...
     End If
```

---

**Example call (including declaration head)**

As additional feature this flexible example call not only displays

- **node names** and
- **text contents** (including possible `<!-- comments -->`),
- but also outputs a chapter-like **id** in the first target column. So the subordinated childnodes to the `<Me>` parent node (id# `6`) will be marked by `6.1` and `6.2`.

To *memorize* hierarchy levels a user defined type gets defined in the code module's declaration head.

(Note that I used the original xml content not changing the possible typo "exmaple111" in node `Example [@id='exmaple111']`).*

Of course the initial *XPath* search can be modified to any other subnode request.

```
Option Explicit                         ' declaration head of code module
Type TLevels                            ' user defined type
    levels() As Long
    oldies() As String
End Type
Dim mem As TLevels                      ' declare array container for u.d.type

Sub ExampleCall()
    ReDim mem.levels(0 To 4)            ' define current level count
    ReDim mem.oldies(0 To 4)            ' define level ids
    
    Dim xFileName As String
    xFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\hierarchy.xml"  ' << change to your needs
    
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.validateOnParse = False

    If xDoc.Load(xFileName) Then
        ' [1] write xml info to array with exact or assumed items count
        Dim data As Variant: ReDim data(1 To xDoc.SelectNodes("//*").Length, 1 To 3)
        '     start call of recursive function
        listChildNodes xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Example[@id='exmaple111']"), data ' call help function listChildNodes

        ' [2] write results to target sheet                 ' << change to project's sheet Code(name)
        With Sheet1                       
            Dim r As Long, c As Long
            r = UBound(data): c = UBound(data, 2)
            'write titles
            .Range("A1").Resize(r, c) = ""                  ' clear result range
            .Range("A1").Resize(1, c) = Split("ID,NodeName,Text", ",") ' titles
            'write data field array to target
            .Range("A2").Resize(r, c) = data                ' get  2-dim data array
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Load Error " & xFileName
    End If
    Set xDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: Output]

**Recursive main function `listChildNodes()`**

**Note** that late binding XML doesn't allow the use of IXMLDOMNodeType enumeration constants

```
e.g. 1 ... `NODE_ELEMENT`, 2 ... `NODE_ATTRIBUTE`, 3 ... `NODE_TEXT` etc.,
```

so you have to take the numeric equivalents.

```
Function listChildNodes(curNode As Object, _
                        ByRef v As Variant, _
                        Optional ByRef i As Long = 1, _
                        Optional curLvl As Long = 0 _
                        ) As Boolean
' Purpose: assign the complete node structure to a 1-based 2-dim array
' Author:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
' Date:    2021-04-04
    ' Escape clause
    If curNode Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If i < 1 Then i = 1                          ' one based items Counter
    ' Increase array size .. if needed
    If i >= UBound(v) Then                       ' change array size if needed
        Dim tmp As Variant
        tmp = Application.Transpose(v)           ' change rows to columns
        ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(v) + 1000) ' increase row numbers
        v = Application.Transpose(tmp)           ' transpose back
        Erase tmp
    End If

    ' Declare variables
    Dim child      As Object                     ' late bound node object
    Dim bDisplay   As Boolean
    Dim prevLvl    As Long

    ' Distinguish between different node types
    Select Case curNode.NodeType

    Case 3                                       ' 3 ... NODE_TEXT
        ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' A. It's nothing but a TextNode (i.e. a parent node's firstChild!)
        ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   write pure text content (NODE_TEXT) of parent elements
        v(i, 3) = curNode.Text                   ' nodeValue of text node
        ' return boolean (i.e. yes, I'v found no further child elements)
        listChildNodes = True
        Exit Function

    Case 1                                       ' 1 ... NODE_ELEMENT
        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        ' B.1 NODE_ELEMENT WITHOUT text node immediately below,
        '     a) i.e. node followed by another node element <..>,
        '        (i.e. FirstChild.NodeType MUST not be of type NODE_TEXT = 3)
        '     b) or node element without any child node
        '     Note: a text content (NODE_TEXT) actually is a child node(!) to an element node
        '           (see section A. getting the FirstChild of a NODE_ELEMENT)
        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        If curNode.HasChildNodes Then
            ' a) display element followed by other Element nodes
            If Not curNode.FirstChild.NodeType = 3 Then ' <>3 ... not a NODE_TEXT
                bDisplay = True
            End If
        Else                                     ' empty NODE_ELEMENT
            ' b) always display an empty node element
            bDisplay = True
        End If
     
        If bDisplay Then
            'write id + nodename
            v(i, 1) = getID(v, i, curLvl)
            v(i, 2) = curNode.nodeName
            v(i, 2) = v(i, 2) & " " & getAtts(curNode)
            i = i + 1
        End If

        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        ' B.2 check child nodes via recursion
        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        For Each child In curNode.ChildNodes
            ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            ' >> recursive call <<
            ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            bDisplay = listChildNodes(child, v, i, curLvl + 1)
            
            If bDisplay Then
                'write id + nodename
                v(i, 1) = getID(v, i, curLvl)
                v(i, 2) = curNode.nodeName
                v(i, 2) = v(i, 2) & " " & getAtts(curNode)
                i = i + 1                        ' increment counter
            End If
        Next child

    Case 8                                       ' 8 ... NODE_COMMENT
        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        ' C. Comment
        ' --------------------------------------------------------------
        v(i, 1) = getID(v, i, curLvl)
        v(i, 2) = curNode.nodeName
        v(i, 3) = "'<!-- " & curNode.NodeValue & "-->"
        i = i + 1                                ' increment counter
    End Select

End Function
```

**Help function `getID()`**

Returns a chapter-like level numbering (here in target column `A:A`)

```
Function getID(v, i, curLvl As Long) As String
'Purpose: return chapter-like level id
'Note   : called by recursive function listChildNodes()
'Author : https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'Date   : 2021-04-04
    
    'a) get previous level
    Dim prevLvl As Long
    If i > 1 Then prevLvl = UBound(Split(v(i - 1, 1), ".")) + 1
    
    If curLvl Then
        Dim lvl As Long
        'b) reset previous levels
        If curLvl < prevLvl Then
            For lvl = curLvl + 1 To UBound(mem.levels)
                mem.levels(lvl) = 0
            Next
        ElseIf curLvl > prevLvl Then
            mem.levels(curLvl) = 0
        End If
        'c) increment counter
        mem.levels(curLvl) = mem.levels(curLvl) + 1
        'd) create id and remember old one
        getID = "'" & Mid(mem.oldies(curLvl - 1), 2) & IIf(curLvl > 1, ".", "") & mem.levels(curLvl)
        mem.oldies(curLvl) = getID
    End If
End Function
```

**Help function `getAtts()`**

Additional feature returning attribute names and values (column `B:B`):

```
Function getAtts(ByRef node As Object) As String
' Purpose: return attribute(s) string, e.g. 'id="example111"]'
' Note:    called by recursive function listChildNodes()
' Author:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
  If node.nodeName = "#comment" Then Exit Function
  Dim sAtts As String, ii As Long
  If node.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
      ii = 0: sAtts = ""
      For ii = 0 To node.Attributes.Length - 1
          sAtts = sAtts & "[@" & node.Attributes.Item(ii).nodeName & "='" & node.Attributes.Item(ii).NodeValue & "']"
      Next ii
  End If
' return function value
  getAtts = sAtts
End Function
```