# how to continue a macro if above "if" is true

Tags: excel, vba

So I have the above code, I want to continue on this logic: if K4 is not empty then copy L3 to L4 and so on, until one cell is empty (for example K32 is not empty then copy L31 to L32, but if K33 is empty then stop)
Im sorry if this is a basic question, I have just started working with VBA.
Thank you in advance

```
   Sub kepletmasolos()

Sheets("XTR MSTR").Select

 If IsEmpty(Range("K3").Value) = False Then

      Range("L2").Copy Range("L3")

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There are numerous example how to loop through a given range, e.g. [Loop through each cell ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through each cell in a range of cells when given a Range object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using a `Do` loop:

```
Sub kepletmasolos()

Dim r As Long: r = 3

With Sheets("XTR MSTR")
    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(r, "K"))
        '.Cells(r, "L").Value = .Cells(r - 1, "L").Value
        .Cells(r - 1, "L").copy .Cells(r, "L")
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: okay, and lets say the cell "L3" contains a formula =SUM(N3;P3;R3)
and i want the "L4" cell to contain =SUM(N4;P4;R4) and so on
how do you do that?
thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Probably simplest to just revert to copy/paste - code amended above.

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

new to VBA myself, Just thought i would through my idea in?

row = where you would start, let me know what you think.

```
Sub kepletmasolos()

Dim Row As Long 
Row = 1

Start:
With Sheets("XTR MSTR")
    If Not isEmpty(.Cells(Row, "K")) Then
        .Cells(Row, "L").Copy .Cells(Row + 1, "L")
        Row = Row + 1
        GoTo Start
    Else
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: `GoTo` is widely considered as harmful to structured programming (originating in former BASIC times with excessive *Spaghetti programming*) - except its use in error handling; c.f. [GoTo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) or [GoTo still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)